# Expand a time series from every 15 minutes to 10 seconds in R

Tags: r, time-series

I have the following data set, abbreviated for simplicity:
SM = soil moisture, T = Temperature

```
DateTime              SMCount      T1        T2      T3  
2023-04-24 11:45:00   3960        12.875   15.625   17.5  
2023-04-24 12:00:00   3951        13.00    15.375   17.125         
2023-04-24 12:15:00   3955        13.25    15.6875  17.5  
2023-04-24 12:30:00   3961        13.1875  14.75    15.875
```

etc.

I would like to create the following:

```
DateTime              SMCount      T1        T2      T3  
2023-04-24 11:45:00   3960        12.875   15.625   17.5  
2023-04-24 11:45:10   3960        12.875   15.625   17.5  
2023-04-24 11:45:20   3960        12.875   15.625   17.5  
2023-04-24 11:45:30   3960        12.875   15.625   17.5
```

... and so on

```
2023-04-24 12:00:00   3951        13.00    15.375   17.125   
2023-04-24 12:00:10   3951        13.00    15.375   17.125   
2023-04-24 12:00:20   3951        13.00    15.375   17.125   
2023-04-24 12:00:30   3951        13.00    15.375   17.125
```

... and so on

```
2023-04-24 12:15:00   3955        13.25    15.6875  17.5   
2023-04-24 12:15:10   3955        13.25    15.6875  17.5   
2023-04-24 12:15:20   3955        13.25    15.6875  17.5   
2023-04-24 12:15:30   3955        13.25    15.6875  17.5
```

... and so on

```
2023-04-24 12:30:00   3961        13.1875  14.75    15.875   
2023-04-24 12:30:10   3961        13.1875  14.75    15.875   
2023-04-24 12:30:20   3961        13.1875  14.75    15.875   
2023-04-24 12:30:30   3961        13.1875  14.75    15.875
```

... and so on

I searched for the problem and came across two possible solutions I was trying to adapt:

Solution 1:

```
library(tidyr)
df <- complete(soilmoisture$DateTime = seq(from = min(soilmoisture$DateTime), to = max(soilmoisture$DateTime), by = 1)) %>%
  fill(SMCount)
```

Solution 2:

```
library(tidyverse)
data <- mutate(soilmoisture$DateTime = lubridate::ymd_hms(soilmoisture$DateTime))%>%
  complete(soilmoisture$DateTime = seq.POSIXt(min(soilmoisture$Datetime), max(soilmoisture$DateTime), by="sec"))%>%
  fill(SMCount)
```

I'm getting the following error messages, respectively:

> ```
> Error: unexpected '=' in "df %>% complete(soilmoisture$DateTime="  
> and  
> Error: unexpected '=' in "data <- mutate(soilmoisture$DateTime ="
> ```

Any idea how to fix it?
And how do I adapt my code that so that SMCount, T1, T2 and T3 are all filled in at the same time?

Many thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Could you please provide your dataset sample (for instance `dput(soilmoisture)`) and show the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try this, please let me know if this is what you were expecting

```
data <- structure(list(DateTime = structure(c(1682336700, 1682337600, 
                                             1682338500, 1682339400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
                      SMCount = c(3960L, 3951L, 3955L, 3961L), T1 = c(12.875, 13, 
                                                                      13.25, 13.1875), T2 = c(15.625, 15.375, 15.6875, 14.75), 
                      T3 = c(17.5, 17.125, 17.5, 15.875)), row.names = c(NA, -4L
                      ), class = "data.frame")
```

**Code**

```
  dfs <- data %>% 
  complete(DateTime = seq(from = min(DateTime), to = max(DateTime), by = 1)) %>%
  fill(SMCount,T1, T2, T3,.direction='down')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```r
library(tidyverse)

SoilMoisture %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  reframe(DateTime = DateTime + seq(0, 890, 10), SMCount, T1, T2, T3)
#> # A tibble: 360 x 5
#>    DateTime            SMCount    T1    T2    T3
#>    <dttm>                <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 2023-04-24 11:45:00    3960  12.9  15.6  17.5
#>  2 2023-04-24 11:45:10    3960  12.9  15.6  17.5
#>  3 2023-04-24 11:45:20    3960  12.9  15.6  17.5
#>  4 2023-04-24 11:45:30    3960  12.9  15.6  17.5
#>  5 2023-04-24 11:45:40    3960  12.9  15.6  17.5
#>  6 2023-04-24 11:45:50    3960  12.9  15.6  17.5
#>  7 2023-04-24 11:46:00    3960  12.9  15.6  17.5
#>  8 2023-04-24 11:46:10    3960  12.9  15.6  17.5
#>  9 2023-04-24 11:46:20    3960  12.9  15.6  17.5
#> 10 2023-04-24 11:46:30    3960  12.9  15.6  17.5
#> # ... with 350 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

**Question data in reproducible format**

```r
SoilMoisture <- structure(list(DateTime = structure(c(1682333100, 1682334000, 
1682334900, 1682335800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    SMCount = c(3960L, 3951L, 3955L, 3961L), T1 = c(12.875, 13, 
    13.25, 13.1875), T2 = c(15.625, 15.375, 15.6875, 14.75), 
    T3 = c(17.5, 17.125, 17.5, 15.875)), row.names = c(NA, -4L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `merge` it to a `'10 sec'` `seq`uence of the datetime `range`, then `zoo::na.locf`,

```
dat |>
  merge(
    data.frame(DateTime=do.call(seq, c(as.list(range(dat$DateTime)), '10 sec'))), 
    all=TRUE) |> zoo::na.locf()
#                DateTime SMCount     T1      T2     T3
# 1   2023-04-24 11:45:00    3960 12.875 15.6250 17.500
# 2   2023-04-24 11:45:10    3960 12.875 15.6250 17.500
# 3   2023-04-24 11:45:20    3960 12.875 15.6250 17.500
# 4   2023-04-24 11:45:30    3960 12.875 15.6250 17.500
# ...
# 91  2023-04-24 12:00:00    3951 13.000 15.3750 17.125
# 92  2023-04-24 12:00:10    3951 13.000 15.3750 17.125
# 93  2023-04-24 12:00:20    3951 13.000 15.3750 17.125
# 94  2023-04-24 12:00:30    3951 13.000 15.3750 17.125
# ...
# 181 2023-04-24 12:15:00    3955 13.250 15.6875 17.500
# 182 2023-04-24 12:15:10    3955 13.250 15.6875 17.500
# 183 2023-04-24 12:15:20    3955 13.250 15.6875 17.500
# 184 2023-04-24 12:15:30    3955 13.250 15.6875 17.500
```

---

*Data>*

```
dat <- structure(list(DateTime = structure(c(1682329500, 1682330400, 
1682331300, 1682332200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    SMCount = c(3960L, 3951L, 3955L, 3961L), T1 = c(12.875, 13, 
    13.25, 13.1875), T2 = c(15.625, 15.375, 15.6875, 14.75), 
    T3 = c(17.5, 17.125, 17.5, 15.875)), row.names = c(NA, -4L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: First answer by PKumar was the best and easiest. Second and third answers produced duplicate time stamps for some reason (these can be removed, of course) but they also produced an additional 15 minutes of data at the end of the data frame. Many thanks for everyone's input, much appreciated!